# how to fill contours in python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have binary image of contours (left picture)
I am trying to fill contours like right picture
I tried using findcontours and drawcontours to fill inside the contours and it doesn't seem to work

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Fwq.png)

here is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gD78.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(diff, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(diff,[c], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,20))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(diff, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=2)
show(diff)
```